# jquery validation working on some browsers, but not on others

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate, validation

Why does this work for some people, and doesn't for others? Others just click the button and it doesn't work. It started doing that after I added the nospaces validation method. Any suggestions would be very much appreciated.

```
<form method="post" action="#" id="client_form" class="order-form">
<input type="text" id="user_name" name="user_name" class="req nospaces" />
</form>
 <button id="client_next_btn"><?php echo($content->getString('order')); ?></button>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(function ()
{
jQuery.validator.addClassRules('req', { required: function (el) { return $(el).is(':visible') } });

var nums = ['0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9'];
var letters = ['q','w','e','r','t','y','u','i','o','p','a','s','d','f','g','h','j','k','l','z','x','c','v','b','n','m'];
var alphanumeric = nums.concat(letters);

jQuery.validator.addMethod("nospaces", function(value, element) {
    var val = value.split("");
    var bool = true;
    for (var i in val)
    {
        if (jQuery.inArray(val[i], alphanumeric) == -1)
        {
            bool = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    return bool;
}, "* <?php echo ($content->getString('no_spaces')); ?>");

$('#client_form').validate();
$('#client_next_btn').click(function ()
{
    $('#client_message').empty();

    if ($('#client_form').validate().form())
    {
                alert('works');
            }
    }
```

}

Comment: jsFiddle and tweak it until there are no errors, unless you copied it bad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just after I posted the question, I figured out the answer - addMethod has to go together with addClassRules and not by itself

Answer (score 1):

Just as a tip, you can get rid of this:

```
jQuery.validator.addClassRules('req', { 
  required: function (el) { return $(el).is(':visible') } 
});
```

and use the built in [`required`](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Methods/required) class, just add the [`ignore` option](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#toptions) to your [`.validate()`](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#options) call to exclude [`:hidden`](http://api.jquery.com/hidden-selector/) elements, like this:

```
$('#client_form').validate({ ignore: ':hidden' });
```